# form_for with classy_enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a Post table with a state field

```
t.string :state
```

I used the [Classy Enum](https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum) gem to create my 3 states with a State generated class

```
class State < ClassyEnum::Base
end

class State::New < State
end

class State::Published < State
end

class State::Hidden < State
end
```

I have a post_controller with an update method

In my view I have this form to submit the change

```
<%= form_for @post, method: :patch do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field state: "published" %>
    <%= f.submit "Share", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
```

Why I get this error?

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `{:state=>"published"}' for #<Post:0x00007f973fe62ef8>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `state:string` in Post model

`rails g migration add_state_to_posts state`

Or

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ClassyEnum::ActiveRecord

  classy_enum_attr :state

end
```

Reference => https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum#3-setup-the-active-record-model

Comment: @arnaudjnn Are you still facing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer :

```
<%= link_to 'Publish', post_path, data: {method: :patch, remote: true, params: {state: "published"}.to_param}, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

I just need the form_for way if somebody can help